# prove that there are infinite positive numbers $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}}$ is square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Show that there are infinitely many positive integer  number $A=\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}}$,and $0\le a_{i}\le 9$,such that
>   $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}}$ is a square number.

Here, $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}}=10^{n-1}a_1+10^{n-2}a_2+ \dots 10a_{n-1}+a_n$.

How to prove ? Thank you

Comment: What is the meaning of that straight line ove an *integer* number?

Comment: I presume it means the number with given digits in the decimal system.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It is a number which can be written in the form $a_1 \cdot 10^n+ \dots+10a_{n-1}+ a_n$.

Comment: So **any** number in decimal base, @Inceptio...? I find this odd since I never saw that and, as far as I know and unless stated otherwise, we always assume base ten.

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe Inceptio means that $\overline{a_1\ldots a_n}$ can be written as $a_1\cdot 10^n+\cdots+a_n$.

Comment: sorry, my English is very poor ,china problem :http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/167257824.html

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, that's commonly used in contest problems to show that it's just another number in decimal form, and not to confuse with the multiplication of $a_i$'s.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Inceptio. It's clear now.

Comment: @math110: You're welcome. What is your approach?

Comment: @Inceptio  sorry,I have no approach.

Comment: @math110 I see that the site which you linked already has a solution in Chinese. Why are you asking for a solution on MSE?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an observation: $10^{11} + 1$ is divisible by $11^2$. We can use this to get infinitely many numbers of the required form.

Pick and arbitrary natural number $k$. Note that $x = 10^{11(2k+1)}+1$ is divisible by $10^{11}+1$, which in turn means that $x$ is divisible by $11^2$.

For convenience, let's denote $n = 11(2k+1)$. We see that $x=10^n+1$ has $n+1$ digits and looks like $x = \overline{10\ldots01}$, with $n-1$ zeroes in the middle.

Now, look at number $z = x/11^2$. Note that $z$ is an integer, and that $z$ is clearly less that $10^n$. Therefore, $z$ has at most $n$ digits:
$$
z = \overline{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n}.
$$

Note: several leading digits here can happen to equal to $0$, but that seems to be ok.

Now think of what happens when we multiply $x$ by $z$. On the one hand, $xz = x^2 / 11^2 = (x/11)^2$, so $xz$ is clearly a square. On the other hand, $xz = z(10^n+1) = 10^n z + z$. In decimal notation, $10^n z$ looks like $z$ with $n$ zeroes appended on the right. Therefore,
$$
xz = 10^n z + z = \overline{a_1 \ldots a_n a_1 \ldots a_n}.
$$

There it is, we have built an arbitrarily large number $xz$ which is a square and whose decimal representation has the desired property.

*EXAMPLE:* To make things easier, look at the minimal example of this construction, i.e. what happens when we pick $k=0$ (some might say it's not natural, but whatever). Then we have $x = 100000000001$, $x/11 = 9090909091$ and $z = x/11^2 = 826446281$. And our big number:
$$
xz = 82644628100826446281 = 9090909091^2
$$

Comment: what is $y$? Thank you

Comment: $y$ is just some natural number. $y^2$ can be thought of as the largest divisor of $x$ that is a square. $z$ is what remains when you "remove" that divisor from $x$.

Comment: You can think of it in terms of decomposition into primes. If $x = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \ldots p_i^{\alpha_i}$, where $p_j$ are prime numbers, then $y = p_1^{\[\alpha_1 / 2\]} p_2^{\[\alpha_2/2\]} \ldots p_i^{\[\alpha_i/2\]}$.

Comment: and why easy $\overline{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}}=(yz)^2$? Thank you

Comment: You know what, I found a way to simplify this a bit and get rid of square-free things, hold on, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note that $a_1$ turns out to be $0$. If leading zeroes are forbidden, then I don't have a full solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9457/discussion-between-math110-and-dan-shved)

Comment: This is correct. Note that if you want an $n$ digit number (to avoid leading zeros), you can just multiply by $16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81$ or$ 100.